# Transition between two Steppers with independently assigned cues

Tags: arduino

I am going to use two step motors, two easy-drivers, one arduino uno.
Each step motors have gear to rotate, front and back.
First, I'd like to assign multiple rotation cues for each steppers. such as,

```
int step1cue1 = 329
int step1cue2 = 582
int step1cue3 = 1038
int step1 cue4 = 1790
...

int step2cue1 = 568
int step2cue2 = 1004
int step2cue3 = 1928
int step2cue4 = 3592
...

and each stepper needs minimum 0 and maximum value, such as,
int step1maxcue = 8372
int step2maxcue = 8421


each rotation speed and acceleration need to be set and controllable as well.
I would like to use rotation speed = 0 to make the stepper stopped at the cue.
```

** Operation

Both steppers start from 0,
First, stepper1 rotates to randomly chosen cue from its step1cues, when it almost reaches to the chosen cue, stepper2 starts to rotate to randomly chosen cue from step2cues.(stepper1 stopped at the cue with speed=0), when step2 almost reaches to its cue, stepper1 starts to rotate to another randomly chosen step1cue (not the current cue).. (stepper2 stops with speed=0).. and repeat this transition between two steppers.

Could you please help me with this code?

I would like to use the code from this,

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define two steppers and the pins they will use
AccelStepper stepper1(1, 9, 8);
AccelStepper stepper2(1, 7, 6);

int pos1 = 3600;
int pos2 = 5678;

void setup()
{  
  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(3000);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(1000);
  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(2000);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(800);
}

void loop()
{
  if (stepper1.distanceToGo() == 0)
  {
        pos1 = -pos1;
    stepper1.moveTo(pos1);
  }
  if (stepper2.distanceToGo() == 0)
  {
    pos2 = -pos2;
    stepper2.moveTo(pos2);
  }
  stepper1.run();
  stepper2.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the AccelStepper library, so I can be wrong, but this should do what you requested:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// With matrices it's easier
const int step1cues[] = { 329,  582, 1038, 1790 ...};
const int step2cues[] = { 568, 1004, 1928, 3592 ...};

// Define two steppers and the pins they will use
AccelStepper stepper1(1, 9, 8);
AccelStepper stepper2(1, 7, 6);

byte movingStepper;

// Distance from position when the motor should start
#define THRESHOLD 20

void setup()
{
    // A0 should be disconnected. If it is used
    // change this to an unused analog pin
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    stepper1.setMaxSpeed(3000);
    stepper1.setAcceleration(1000);
    stepper2.setMaxSpeed(3000);
    stepper2.setAcceleration(1000);

    // Make sure that steppers are at zero
    stepper1.setCurrentPosition(0);
    stepper2.setCurrentPosition(0);

    // Pretend that we were moving motor 2
    // It is already at position, so first
    // loop will move motor 1 to a new position
    movingStepper = 2;
}


void loop()
{
    if (movingStepper == 1)
    {
        if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step2cues[random(sizeof(step2cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper2.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper2.moveTo(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step1cues[random(sizeof(step1cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper1.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper1.moveTo(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 1;
        }
    }

    stepper1.run();
    stepper2.run();
}
```

`THRESHOLD` is the "almost" in your sentence: when it is nearer than this value it will start moving the other motor. Note: the cues should be mode distant one from the other than twice the threshold value, so you won't have mixed conditions (I mean with that threshold the minimum distance from one cue and ANY other should be 40).

And by the way, you don't need to set speed to 0: when the stepper reaches the position it will halt by itself.

**EDIT:**

The OP asked three more features (print the next cue when chosen, print on serial the current position, set a switch when the motor reaches the cue), so here they are.

First of all I'd separate the second and third feature from the previous code, for clarity reasons. I chose to run that code only when the position changes, but this can easily be changed to

1. print that code only after a fixed amount of change (e.g. only after a change of 50 or more)
2. print that code at fixed amount of time (e.g. 0.5 s)

Anyway, here is the code:

```
int currentPos1 = -1;
int currentPos2 = -1;

void loop()
{
    if (movingStepper == 1)
    {
        if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step2cues[random(sizeof(step2cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper2.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper2.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.print("Next cue for motor 2: ");
            Serial.println(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step1cues[random(sizeof(step1cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper1.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper1.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.print("Next cue for motor 1: ");
            Serial.println(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 1;
        }
    }

    if (currentPos1 != stepper1.currentPosition())
    {   // Stepper 1 has moved
        currentPos1 = stepper1.currentPosition()

        if (stepper1.distanceToGo() == 0)
        { // Stepper 1 has reached the final position
            digitalWrite(switch1, HIGH);
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(switch1, LOW);
        }

        Serial.print("Motor 1 pos: ");
        Serial.println(currentPos1);
    }

    if (currentPos2 != stepper2.currentPosition())
    {   // Stepper 2 has moved
        currentPos2 = stepper2.currentPosition()

        if (stepper2.distanceToGo() == 0)
        { // Stepper 2 has reached the final position
            digitalWrite(switch2, HIGH);
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(switch2, LOW);
        }

        Serial.print("Motor 2 pos: ");
        Serial.println(currentPos2);
    }

    stepper1.run();
    stepper2.run();
}
```

If you choose to modify it in order not to receive frequent motor updates (e.g. by showing the message every half a second) you should move the `Stepper X has reached the final position` block outside the control, so that it can be executed every iteration:

```
unsigned long lastShownMessages = 0;

void loop()
{
    if (movingStepper == 1)
    {
        if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step2cues[random(sizeof(step2cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper2.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper2.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.print("Next cue for motor 2: ");
            Serial.println(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step1cues[random(sizeof(step1cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper1.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper1.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.print("Next cue for motor 1: ");
            Serial.println(nextpos);
            movingStepper = 1;
        }
    }

    if ((millis() - lastShownMessages) > 500)
    { // More than 500 ms passed since last update:
        Serial.print("Motor 1 pos: ");
        Serial.println(stepper1.currentPosition());
        Serial.print("Motor 2 pos: ");
        Serial.println(stepper2.currentPosition());
        lastShownMessages += 500;
    }

    if (stepper1.distanceToGo() == 0)
    { // Stepper 1 has reached the final position
        digitalWrite(switch1, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(switch1, LOW);
    }

    if (stepper2.distanceToGo() == 0)
    { // Stepper 2 has reached the final position
        digitalWrite(switch2, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(switch2, LOW);
    }

    stepper1.run();
    stepper2.run();
}
```

Comment: frarugi87, Thank you so much. Your code does exactly I wanted. I'd like to see each moving motor's cue on the server monitor, where Serial.println should be with which variable? Thanks!!

Comment: @Toshi just before or after the `stepperX.moveTo` instruction; `nextpos` holds the next position that the motor will go

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can I ask for one more thing? I would like to set a switch on using arduino pin when the motor stopped at the cue, and switch off when the motor starts running to the next cue. I attached the code below.

Comment: @Toshi I added the features you requested ;)

Comment: Hello Frarugi87, I would like to add a rotary movement of steppers. 0 to1000 and goes back to 0 in a single motion with a same threshold before back to 0 to start stepper2 movement. Could you help me to add this feature as an independent class, so I could chose from either the single movement and rotary movement on demands. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PLUS, for a calibration purpose, can I see the rotation value (increment) of the stepper on the Server Monitor ? I can set the speed really low and let it roll, then I could know cue values for the stepcues that I need to set.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// With matrices it's easier
const int step1cues[] = {10000 , 20000, 30000 , 40000 , 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000};
const int step2cues[] = {10000 , 20000, 30000 , 40000 , 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000};

// Define two steppers and the pins they will use
AccelStepper stepper1(1, 4, 3);
AccelStepper stepper2(1, 7, 6);

int switch1 = 12;
int switch2 = 13;

byte movingStepper;

// Distance from position when the motor should start
#define THRESHOLD 20

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(switch1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(switch2, OUTPUT);

    // A0 should be disconnected. If it is used
    // change this to an unused analog pin
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

    stepper1.setMaxSpeed(3000);
    stepper1.setAcceleration(1000);
    stepper2.setMaxSpeed(3000);
    stepper2.setAcceleration(1000);

    // Make sure that steppers are at zero
    stepper1.setCurrentPosition(0);
    stepper2.setCurrentPosition(0);

    // Pretend that we were moving motor 2
    // It is already at position, so first
    // loop will move motor 1 to a new position
    movingStepper = 2;
}


void loop()
{
    if (movingStepper == 1)
    {
        if (abs(stepper1.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;

            do
            {
                nextpos = step2cues[random(sizeof(step2cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper2.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper2.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.println("2");
            Serial.println(nextpos);

            movingStepper = 2;

            if ( nextpos = stepper2.targetPosition() ){
              digitalWrite(switch1, HIGH); 
            }
              else {
                digitalWrite(switch1, LOW);
                }
            }


    }
    else
    {
        if (abs(stepper2.distanceToGo()) < THRESHOLD)
        {
            int nextpos;
            do
            {
                nextpos = step1cues[random(sizeof(step1cues)/sizeof(int))];
            } while (abs(nextpos - stepper1.targetPosition()) < THRESHOLD);
            stepper1.moveTo(nextpos);
            Serial.println("1");
            Serial.println(nextpos);

            movingStepper = 1;

            if ( nextpos = stepper1.targetPosition() ){
              digitalWrite(switch2, HIGH); 
            }
              else {
                digitalWrite(switch2, LOW);
                }
            }

    }

    stepper1.run();
    stepper2.run();
}
```